# Click to remove parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, append, clone

I'm struggling for something that seems pretty basic, though I'm not seeing what I am doing wrong.

I want that onClick a certain div is cloned till the maximum of 4 times. (So far so good), and I want to have a remove button that deletes one of the divs inserted.

And my problem is right there. **I can't get the remove button to work.**

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields      = 4; // maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper         = $("#addDriverContent div:first"); 
  var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); // Add button ID
  var x = 0

  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // max input box allowed
    if(x < max_fields) {
      x++; 
      $(wrapper).clone().append('<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>').appendTo($('#clone_wrapper'));}
  });

  // user click on remove text
  $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().sibling('#content').remove();
    x--;
  })

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="addDriverContent" style="display:none;">
  <div id="content">
    Contents
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="add_field_button" id="clone_button">ADD DRIVER</button>
<div id="clone_wrapper"></div>
```

**Take a look at [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/groseler/xm4sesa2/5/)**.

*(I've started with [this example](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery))*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your javascript

1. You are attaching the `click event handler` to wrong element. The element you are attaching to is not even visible on page and is never clicked.
2. Your line where you try to remove the clicked content is wrong. `$(this).parent().remove()` is enough.

[**See Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/xm4sesa2/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 4; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $("#addDriverContent div:first");
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 0

    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++;
            $(wrapper).clone().append('<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>').appendTo($('#clone_wrapper'));
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

Comment: Just beat me to both of these issues! =P +1

Comment: Thank you for your time. I had already tried with parent() now I was trying alternatives.

Comment: Thank you again for this ;)

Answer (score 4):

Change your event listener to the following:

```
$("#clone_wrapper").on("click",".remove_field", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().remove(); x--;
});
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xm4sesa2/8/).

I've made two changes:

1. Change `$(wrapper)` to `$("#clone_wrapper")`. The `.remove_field` links are added to the wrapper clone, not the wrapper itself (from `appendTo($('#clone_wrapper'))`)
2. Change `$(this).parent().sibling('#content')` to `$(this).parent()`. The parent *is* the `#content` — you don't want to remove its sibling.

Comment: jsfiddle not working. I have doubt in the remove, if we have more then 3-4 parents class then how can remove work? for example,<div class="parent"> <div class="a"><input type="text"><input type="text"><input type="text"></div><div class="remove"><span>Remove</span></div></div>

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the new onclick function during the first one, and change your selector like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 4; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $("#addDriverContent div:first"); 
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
var x = 0

$(add_button).click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
 if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; 
        $(wrapper).clone().append('<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>').appendTo($('#clone_wrapper'));
        $(".remove_field").click( function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).parent().remove(); 
            x--;
        })
    }
});

});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thank you very much. I opted for the @ozan answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Lambda Ninja, I admit my explanation is poor so I'm upvoting your answer.  And you're welcome groseler.

Answer (score 1):

I refactored your code, which is more clean and effective. explanations is in comment.

**HTML**

```
<div id="addDriverContent" style="display:none;">

    <!-- if your element is going to cloned, use class instead of id. id should always be unique. -->
    <div class="content">

        <!-- because your content is already invisible, why note put your remove btn in it? -->
        <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>

    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="add_field_button" id="clone_button">ADD DRIVER</button>

<div id="clone_wrapper"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function($) {

var max_fields        = 4; 

// origin selector would select all the first div ancestors.
var $content          = $("#addDriverContent > .content");     

var $clone_wrapper    = $("#clone_wrapper") ;

var $add_button       = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

$add_button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // jquery object is array liked object. Length mean how many elements is selected.
    if ( $clone_wrapper.children(".content").length < max_fields ) 

      $content.clone().appendTo($clone_wrapper);
});

$clone_wrapper.on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // this would be more specific.
    $(this).parent(".content").remove(); 
})

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xm4sesa2/10/